# How to define a b+tree-like structure with c++ recursive templates

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, data-structures

I'm creating a b+ tree like data structure, the difference being each node level is capable of holding different type of values (for caching purposes) and having different amount of children.

E.g.:

- root-node holds up to 8 level1-node children and a value of Struct1,
- level1-node holds up to 16 level2-node children and a value of Struct2,
- level2-node holds up to 32 leaf-node children and a value of Struct 3,
- leaf-node holds a value of StructLeaf.

I don't need tree structure to change at runtime, so I want to use templates to configure it.
I'm expecting instantiation of example above to look something like this:

```
Tree<StructLeaf, <8, Struct1>, <16, Struct2>, <32, Struct3>>()
```

and template definition like this, this is not an actual code, only how I suppose it may look like:

```
// variadic template recursion 'entrypoint'
template<
    typename TLeafData, // do I have to set leaf data before variadic template, even if it is of different structure?
    <int TChildrenSize, typename TData>... TChildNodes> // list of pairs of nodes configurations, how to make it a variadic of pairs?
>
class Node;


// template recursion body
template<
    typename TLeafData, //same as before
    <int TChildrenSize, typename TData> TNode, // values for the current node, how to define a pair?
    <int TChildrenSize, typename TData>... TChildNodes> // same as before
>
class Node {
    TNode.TData data; // how to access TNode.TData?
    std::array<Node<TLeafData, TChildNodes...>, TNode.TChildrenSize> children; // how to pass TChildNodes and access TNode.TChildrenSize?
}


// template recursion end
template<
    typename TLeafData, //same as before
    <> // empty template to stop recursion, how to define it?
>
class Node {
    TLeafData data;
}
```

I see how to make this structure without TData, only with ChildrenSize, by just using recursive template of int, but I also wander if or how is it possible to add data type to the template?

---

I tried using template of template for this, but it looks like it is for another usecase other than passing pairs as I couldn't find a way to access the internal template values.

```
template<template<int A, typename B> typename C>
class AClass {
    C.B data; // type B is unaccessable
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly what you asked but... some suggestions...

1. if you need `strutLead` only in the ground case, put it in the last position of the template parameter list, not in the first position
2. you can "wrap" the dimension and the type of the level as template parameter of an additional type, say it `TWrapper`

So your `tree` variable become

```
Node<TWrapper<8u, Struct1>, TWrapper<16u, Struct2>,
     TWrapper<32u, Struct3>, StructLeaf>  tree;
```

You can realize `Node` declaring and defining `TWrapper`

```
template <std::size_t, typename>
struct TWrapper
{ };
```

and declaring `Node` as follows

```
// template declaration
template <typename, typename...>
class Node;
```

as receiving a mandatory typename and a variadic sequence of typenames

The declaration of the recursion case can simply be a specialization of `Node` as follows

```
// recursion case Node
template <std::size_t Dim, typename TData, typename ... Ts>
class Node<TWrapper<Dim, TData>, Ts...>
{
  TData  data;

  std::array<Node<Ts...>, Dim>  children;
};
```

where you get the dimension of the array and the `TData` type from the first `TWrapper` and you define the following `Node` simply passing the remaining template parameters.

The ground case can be simply written as another specialization of `Node` as follows

```
// groud case Node
template <typename TData>
class Node<TData>
{
  TData  data;
};
```

A full compiling example follows

```
#include <array>

template <std::size_t, typename>
struct TWrapper
{ };

// template declaration
template <typename, typename...>
class Node;

// recursion case Node
template <std::size_t Dim, typename TData, typename ... Ts>
class Node<TWrapper<Dim, TData>, Ts...>
{
  TData  data;

  std::array<Node<Ts...>, Dim>  children;
};

// groud case Node
template <typename TData>
class Node<TData>
{
  TData  data;
};

struct Struct1 {};
struct Struct2 {};
struct Struct3 {};
struct StructLeaf {};

int main()
{
  Node<TWrapper<8u, Struct1>, TWrapper<16u, Struct2>,
       TWrapper<32u, Struct3>, StructLeaf>  tree;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for! Splitting it into templates for Node and TWrapper is the trick. Also, leaf data type at the end is much better, I just wasn't sure it is possible with the variadic template

Answer (score 1):

The naturally recursive way of describing this is for each level only to know about the next, something like:

```
using MyTree = Tree<Struct1, 8,
                    Tree<Struct2, 16,
                         Tree<Struct3, 32,
                              Leaf<StructLeaf>
                              >
                        >
                   >;
```

possibly this should differentiate between the internal node types and the top-level tree, but you get the idea.

---

Note that your code sketch is *not* recursive, but variadic. You can still recurse down that, but it seems like more work than just defining it recursively in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I missed this most obvious solution. I thought the recursive part is in the body (second definition) where I use Node<TLeafData, TChildNodes...> in the array, basically pointing to the same class but with -1 node level.
Now I kinda wonder if it is possible to achieve this with recursion though?

Comment: The other answer shows one way to extract the recursive structure from a flat typelist. The implementation uses recursion whichever layout the type parameters take though, so I'm not sure what you're asking.